# recursive inheritance for overloading a method for a set of template arguments

Tags: c++, inheritance, recursion, overloading, variadic-templates

I need to find a way to recursively build a class given a set of template arguments so that the class inherits from itself and build a method `f` for the current first template argument in the list of template arguments and then inherits from itself by passing on the rest of the list.

So, basically I want to achieve the following interface for a class `C`:

```
C<T1, T2, T3> c;
```

`c` now has methods `C::f(T1)`, `C::f(T2)` and `C::f(T3)`

My approach so far was like this:

```
// primary template
template <class H, class...>
class C {};

// base case where class... is empty
template <class H, class...>
class C<H>
{
public:
    void f(const H& h){
        // std::cout << typeid(h).name() << "\n";
    }
};

// recursive case where T is nonempty
template <class H, class... T>
class C : public C<T...>
{
public:
    void f(const H& h){
        // std::cout << typeid(h).name() << "\n";
    }
};
```

This does not actually compile, as I get

> error: redefinition of 'C' class C : public C

Is my approach basically possible and just a matter of semantically and or syntactically invalid code or does this approach not work in principle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, a class cannot inherit from itself.

Secondly, all that you apparently are trying to accomplish is to have each template parameter generate a class method that takes that class as a parameter.

In which case, something like this should work.

```
template<typename ...> class C;

template<>
class C<> {};

template<typename T, typename ...Args>
class C<T, Args...> : public C<Args...> {

public:

    void f (const T &)
    {
       // Whatever...
    }
};
```

Note that this is not a class inheriting from itself. It's a template instance that inherits from another template instance. Each template instance is a unique class.

Note that you have a single definition of the class method in question here, and not two, as you were trying to do. This is a slight improvement.

Another improvement would be to consider rearranging the class hierarchy in this manner, if it's possible to do this taking into consideration your other class requirements:

```
template<typename T> class F {
public:

    void f (const T &)
    {
    }
};


template<typename ...> class C;

template<>
class C<> {};

template<typename T, typename ...Args>
class C<T, Args...> : public C<Args...> , public F<T> {

};
```

With this approach, whether you use `C<int, float>`, or `C<int, char *>`, the class method will always be declared to be a method of `F<int>`. This cuts down slightly on the resulting code float, since any instance of `C` that includes `int`, for example, will generate a single class method instance, instead of two separate methods like `C<int, float>::f(const int &)` and `C<int, char *>::f(const int &)`, which would, otherwise, be completely identical.

Comment: thanks, but with your second design I get an error: `error: member 'f' found in multiple base classes of different types`

Comment: Might be able to work around it by adding `using F<T>::f;` and `using C<Args...>::f;` to the main template.

Comment: Ok, will try that, but I noticed something else: With your first design for the following program `int main(){

    C<char, int, double> c;

    int i = 10;
    char ch = 'a';

    c.f(i);
    c.f(ch);
}` I get as output `c c`... meaning the only the overload for the first template argument gets called. Note that i have `std::cout << typeid(T).name() << "\n";` in `C::f`

Comment: You probably need  `using` as well. My answer is limited solely to declaring the methods, which is the only thing that was asked.

Comment: Hmm, I'm sorry, but I don't quite get it yet. Why exactly and also where exactly do I need `using`? If the class inherits the other specialisations then why is it necessary to use `using` somewhere?

Comment: Could you tell me if the pattern you used in the first example has a name? The guides on partial template specialization don't quite match it and I would like to read up on that pattern as it is not quite clear to me yet how it works --- why the base case with empty brackets needs to be like that exactly and so on.

Comment: I can't say if it has an official name, or not. I am not really a big fan of buzzword bingo.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative approach, I'm proposing a solution based on mixins. Feel free to ignore the boilerplate introduced by class `type_name`, the purpose of which is to show you that the right *part* is picked up on a per argument base.

It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<utility>
#include<iostream>

template<typename> struct type_name;
template<> struct type_name<int> { static const char *name; };
template<> struct type_name<double> { static const char *name; };
template<> struct type_name<char> { static const char *name; };

const char * type_name<int>::name = "int";
const char * type_name<double>::name = "double";
const char * type_name<char>::name = "char";

template<typename T>
struct Part {
    void func(T t) {
        std::cout << type_name<T>::name << ": " << t << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename... T>
struct S: private Part<T>... {
    template<typename... Args>
    void f(Args&&... args) {
        using acc_t = int[];
        acc_t acc = { 0, (Part<std::decay_t<Args>>::func(std::forward<Args>(args)), 0)... };
        (void)acc;
    }
};

int main() {
    S<int, double, char> s;
    s.f(42);
    s.f(0.1);
    s.f('c');
    s.f('a', 0.3, 23);
}
```

Some plus of this method:

- `Part<T>` is defined only once for any `T`, no matter how many times you use it in different packs.
- `S<T, T>` is rejected at compile-time and more in general all those packs that contain the same type two or more times. They would otherwise give births to multiple definitions of `f(T)` and a subsequent call would be probably ambiguous.
- You can invoke `f` with a single parameter, as requested. Anyway, as shown in the example, you can invoke `f` with `N` parameters and the call is equivalent to `N` calls to `f` with a single parameter.
  In other terms, you can either use this:

  ```
  s.f('a', 0.3, 23);
  ```

  Or this:

  ```
  s.f('a');
  s.f(0.3);
  s.f(23);
  ```

  The result will be the same in both cases.
  This feature can be easily turned off if needed by defining `S` as it follows:

  ```
  template<typename... T>
  struct S: private Part<T>... {
      template<typename U>
      void f(U &&u) {
          Part<std::decay_t<U>>::func(std::forward<U>(u));
      }
  };
  ```

See it running on [wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/IRYo5MZx4RF9TRyA).

---

As a side note, this is the usual trick used to emulate fold expressions in C++14:

```
template<typename... Args>
void f(Args&&... args) {
    using acc_t = int[];
    acc_t acc = { 0, (Part<std::decay_t<Args>>::func(std::forward<Args>(args)), 0)... };
    (void)acc;
 }
```

You can find more about that on SO as well as on the web.