# requirements on base cases for recursive template class definitions

Tags: c++, class, recursion, template-specialization

To a question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42322204/recursive-inheritance-for-overloading-a-method-for-a-set-of-template-arguments/42322297?noredirect=1#comment71799359_42322297), I got the suggestion to use a general pattern like this to solve my problem:

```
template <class... T>
class C;

template <>
class C<>
{
public:
    void f() {}
};

template <class T, class... Args>
class C<T, Args...> : public C<Args...>
{
public:
    using C<Args...>::f;
    void f(const T& t) { /*stuff*/ }
};
```

Now, I don't fully understand why this pattern has to be like this, so I tried to adapt it by a hypothesis I had about how this works. In the adaption I wanted to end the recursion in a base case with 1 and not 0 template arguments, so I changed the snippet as follows:

```
template <class V, class... >
class C;

template <class V>
class C
{
public:
    void f() {}
};

template <class V, class T, class... Args>
class C<V, T, Args...> : public C<V, Args...>
{
public:
    using C<Args...>::f;
    void f(const T& t) { /*stuff*/ }
};
```

Here `V` is supposed to keep getting passed on until `Args...` is empty, then

```
template <class V>
class C
{
public:
    void f() {}
};
```

is supposed to be chosen. However this throws an error:

```
error: too few template parameters in template redeclaration
template <class V>
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

note: previous template declaration is here
template <class V, class... >
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

So my hypothesis was wrong. How does this actually work and what would be the correct changes for my adaption need to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two errors here:
First, incorrect specialization:

```
template <class V>
class C
{
    //...
};
```

Should be:

```
template <class V>
class C<V>
{
    //...
};
```

Second, incorrect `using` declaration:

```
using C<Args...>::f;
```

Should be:

```
using C<V, Args...>::f;
```

Comment: thanks, why is `<V>` required in `template <class V> class C<V>` though? Afteral there is only that one template parameter.

Comment: That is specialization syntax, `C` is base case, and `C<V>` is specialization case for single template parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the spell the specialization correctly:

```
template <class V>
class C<V>
//    ^^^^  you missed this
```